# Why created Activity background is transparent?

Tags: android, android-activity, view, android-theme

I have created an App with target version 26. when i created Activity background is transparent in default. find attached image

[image]

I know that if we give background color problem will be solved. But, i don't want to background color in every page. Please suggest any idea to solve this

Comment: i dont undrstand your problem

Comment: problem is if we create new activity background color will be whit in default. but here its in Transparent color. Check above image when i open navigation background is transparent in default @Radesh

Comment: i think you give background to All of view in style.xml currect?\

Comment: thanks, i have solved it. check below my answer

Answer (score 1):

you set below line in your style.xml

`name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>`

that change your default background for hole app so just remove this line and it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved.
Actually what happens is while creating application in style.xml
`<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>`

window background is set to null. So, my application default background is transparent without color. After removing that my problem solved